# How can I create many new objects with different changes to the parameters?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation, forecasting

A fully reproducible example.

```
library(forecast)
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)

productB = rep("B",48)
productB = rep("B",48)
productA = rep("A",48)
productA = rep("A",48)

subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b2 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b3 <-c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b4 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
```

Created the dataframe below

```
dfone <- data.frame("date"= rep(date,4),
            "product"= c(rep(productB,2),rep(productA,2)),
            "subproduct"= 
c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
            "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))

export_df <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3])
```

## Creation of data frames based off UNIQUE SUBPRODUCTS

```
dummy_list <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3]) %>% lapply( function(x) 
x[(names(x) %in% c("date", "actuals"))])
dummy_list <-  lapply(dummy_list, function(x) { x["date"] <- NULL; x })


list_dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dfone$subproduct))) {
  #assign(paste0("df", i), as.data.frame(dummy_list[[i]]))
  list_dfs <-append(list_dfs,dummy_list[[i]])
}

combined_dfs <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE,  
by='date'), list(list_dfs))
```

Creating the time series

```
list_ts <- lapply(list_dfs, function(t) 
ts(t,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2021,6), frequency = 12)) %>%
  lapply( function(t) ts_split(t,sample.out=(0.2*length(t))))    # 
creates my train test split
list_ts <- do.call("rbind", list_ts)  #Creates a list of time series
```

Question: If I wanted to create 10 new model objects like below with alpha = 0.1,0.2,0.3.... to 1.0. Is there a way to automate the process below without having to create 10 seperate model_tune_ses1's in code?

```
model_tune_ses1 <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=0.1))) 
model_tune_ses1 <- lapply(model_tune_ses1, "[",  c("mean"))

model_tune_ses2 <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=0.2))) 
model_tune_ses2 <- lapply(model_tune_ses2, "[",  c("mean"))

etc...
```

Edit: This doesn't give me more than 9 models. I'd want a model for n1 =.1 n2=.99 and n3= .3 for example so we would have way more than 9 models for this.

```
n1 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)
n2 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)
n3 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)

out<- lapply(seq_along(n1), function(i) {
   cw_triple_holtwinters_additive <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
       forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha = 
n1[i],beta=n2[i],gamma=n3[i])))
    cw_triple_holtwinters_additive <- 
 lapply(cw_triple_holtwinters_additive, "[", "mean")
  assign(paste0("cw_triple_holtwinters_additive", i), 
cw_triple_holtwinters_additive, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 cw_triple_holtwinters_additive})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a nested loop

```
n1 <- seq(0.1, 0.5, by = 0.1)

out <- lapply(seq_along(n1), function(i) {
    model_tune_ses <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
           forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha = n1[i])))
    model_tune_ses <- lapply(model_tune_ses, "[", "mean")
    assign(paste0("model_tune_ses", i), model_tune_ses, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    model_tune_ses
    
    
       })
```

Check for the objects created

```
ls(pattern = 'model_tune_ses')
[1] "model_tune_ses1" "model_tune_ses2" "model_tune_ses3" "model_tune_ses4" "model_tune_ses5"
```

Comment: I know it's bad practice to create new object names, but is it possible that the output can go directly into environment as in your example 5 different objects?

Comment: Quick question, if I had 3 parameters I wanted to change at the same time. So imagine if this ses() function had a beta= and gamma= arguement. Shall I do the same format as above ? Testing right now.

Comment: @chriswang123 Are those corresponding values.  You can use the same method ie by looping across the length as `seq_along(n1)` as long as all the parameter looped have the same length

Comment: Idk what you mean by corresponding values, but they would be formatted the same way as n1 and the alpha=n1[i] argument. Edit: Got it.

Comment: @chriswang123 i updated the comment i.e. if you have n2, n3, for beta, gamma and those have the same length as n1.  THen, just use the seq_along(n1) use `n1[i]`, `n2[i]`, etc.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the post. The problem with that is it only creates in my example only 9 models, when it should create way more than 9. I'd like it so a potential model can be n1=.1 n2= .9 n3 = .3. Got it.

Comment: @chriswang123 can you please post as new question as this would be new

Comment: I can't post for 90 mins, I'll let you know when I've made a new question.